# How to export "IIS Express Development Certificate" to another computer to connect to local IIS via https connection?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, iis-7, self-signed

My goal is to test my Web Application via the HTTPS connection accessible from another computer on my local network. I have already installed the `IIS Express Development Certificate` on the computer where I develop the application, so when I open my site from the Visual Studio using a URL as such:

```
https://localhost:44234/MyWebApp/Index.aspx
```

It opens in a web browser just fine.

I also exported & then imported that `IIS Express Development Certificate` to another computer on the local network & added it to `Certificates (Local Computer)/Trusted Root Certification Authorities` node.

But the issue is that to access this web app from another local computer (hosted in IIS) I have to use the host computer's IP, as such:

```
https://192.168.1.234:44234/MyWebApp/Index.aspx
```

but that creates the following cert warning in a web browser:

[image]

So is there a way to make this work on another local computer?

Answer (score 2):

That certificate was issued to `localhost` (CN, aka common name) which is only valid on the machine itself.

To suppress the warning, you cannot use such certificates, but one that has the machine name as CN. Then the host name in browser's URL matches the certificate's CN, and the warning will go away.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying that I need to change the CN from `localhost` to `192.168.1.234`, right. If so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by creating a self-signed certificate (with specific CN) using the [SelfSSL tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17275) following [these](http://hansolav.net/blog/SelfsignedSSLCertificatesOnIIS7AndCommonNames.aspx) or [these](http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/) instructions.